# Issue with downloading and installing Google App Engine plugin for Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I'm trying to download and install the plugin for eclipse, and I have Eclipse-Luna 4.4.2 Service Release 2. I followed the tutorials about adding https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.4 to the install new software tab, but each time when I choose what need to be installed, I get the following error :

> An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
>   session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.commons.collections,3.2.0.v2013030210310
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.velocity,1.5.0.v200905192330
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity,1.2.11.v201401230755
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.db.generic,1.0.1.v201107221459
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.db.generic.ui,1.0.2.v201211200622
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.sqm.core,1.2.8.v201401230755
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui,1.2.4.v201212070447
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.jdt.classpath,1.0.1.v201107221501
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.help,1.5.0.v200906020553
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.modelbase.dbdefinition,1.0.2.v201107221519
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.modelbase.sql,1.0.6.v201208230744
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.modelbase.sql.query,1.1.4.v201212120619
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.editor.core,1.0.3.v201212120623
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.result,1.1.6.v201402080246
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.sql,1.0.1.v201110050515
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.codegen,2.10.0.v20150123-0452
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jem,2.0.600.v201302011850
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jem.workbench,2.0.400.v201302011850
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.common.core,1.4.0.v201310142259
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.common.ui,1.4.0.v201310142259
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.common.utility,2.3.0.v201311210251
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.annotate,1.0.100.v201310142259
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core,3.4.0.v201401221940
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.db,2.2.100.v201311210251
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.db.ui,2.1.100.v201310142259
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.gen,2.3.100.v201310142259
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.ui,3.4.0.v201312050012
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.common.annotations.controller,1.1.300.v201302011850
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.common.annotations.core,1.1.300.v201302011850
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.common.frameworks,1.1.601.v201302011850
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.common.project.facet.core,1.4.400.v201403261500
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.common.project.facet.ui,1.4.510.v201501141810
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.common.ui,1.0.201.v201208292200
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.j2ee,1.1.802.v201502041526
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.core,1.3.100.v201404161600
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.ejb,1.1.800.v201404021630
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.ejb.annotation.model,1.1.300.v201004110730
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.jca,1.1.700.v201305311500
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.ui,1.1.801.v201501141713
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.web,1.1.810.v201501141727
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.jee,1.0.700.v201404092030
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.server.core,1.2.400.v20130918_1641
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.pde.build,3.9.0.v20140415-2029
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.pde.core,3.10.2.v20150127-1015
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql,2.6.0.v20140809-296a69f
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.ui,1.4.500.v201409111446
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.css.core,1.1.800.v201402172110
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.css.ui,1.0.901.v201501212057
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.html.core,1.1.802.v201501312139
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.html.ui,1.0.902.v201501212057
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.internet.monitor.core,1.0.600.v20130918_1641
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core,1.3.300.v201410221502
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.manipulation,1.0.500.v201402131232
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui,1.1.500.v201409121658
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.server.discovery,1.0.501.v201501132217
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.server.ui,1.5.100.v201407281532
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.web,1.1.800.v201312041500
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.web.ui,1.1.600.v201302011850
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.jdom,1.1.1.v201101151400

I searched a lot and tried removing the s letter from https, and I turned off all the firewalls, unchecked the "Contact all update sites during installation to find the required software". I even downloaded eclipse ADT on a new machine to try and download the plugin, but it gave me another error.

Is there anything I could or need to do?

Comment: I have downloaded eclipse Luna 4.4 and it works, but if there is anything to do about Luna 4.4.2 please tell me.

Comment: I could install with no error in 4.4.1. I could try and reproduce the error with 4.4.2.

Comment: If you succeed with 4.4.2 can you tell me how? i believe that there is no way since the versions are different.

Answer (score 1):

Change your update site from `https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.4` to `https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.4/` (with the added `/` at the end).

Answer (score 0):

faced same error with 4.4.2, and succeed by replace Luna update site url with http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna/